# Modifying auto suggest to allow multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing Ajax auto suggest function in a form, with the input field being like this:

```
<input type="text" name="model" id="search" maxlength="30" value="Model "onfocus="if(this.value == 'Model ') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Model ';" />
```

and the pertinent line in my js file like this:

```
var inputBox = $('input[name="model"]');
```

I want to extend the function of this form which means I will have multiple instances of the model field, so I changed the name of the field to use:

```
model_' . $i
```

where `$i` is auto incremented with each iteration, resulting in generated html like:

```
<input type="text" name="model_1" id="search" maxlength="30" value="Model " onfocus="if(this.value == 'Model ') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Model: ';" />
<input type="text" name="model_2" id="search" maxlength="30" value="Model " onfocus="if(this.value == 'Model ') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Model: ';" />
```

I'm not sure how I get the js to follow this new naming convention.
I'm really not good with js, so this was a long shot, but didn't work

```
var inputBox = $('input[name="model_<?php echo $i; ?>"]');
```

Is there a js method of just reading the first portion of the field name and ignoring everything after the underscore, or is that not how it's done?

What is the correct method of achieving this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `.auto-suggest` as the selector and give the inputs you want to have the auto-suggest on that class?

Comment: And a few hundred other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+name+starts+with

Comment: @freedomn-m Always helps when you know what terms to actually use for a search though ;)